# Can icloud locked iphone use to build xcode project after DNS bypass?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have iCloud locked phone. If i make DNS bypass, can i use it for development purpose? I mean, Can iCloud locked iPhone use to build Xcode project after DNS bypass? 
Is it possible?